# codeigniter database select comparing strings

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a select in one of my models of my codeigniter project.
I have used the method you will see next on some other functions and never had problems since i was comparing `int`s and not `string`s. However, now i'm comparing strings the select is not done correctly since it doesn't return any results.

```
public function get_frasesr_by_cee($ficha_id){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela_cee_r where id_ficha='".$ficha_id."';");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    //var_dump($query->result());

    $nomes_frasesr_cee;
    $i=0;

    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $nomes_frasesr_cee[$i]=$row->cod_frase_r;
        //var_dump("Ola");
        $i++;
    }

    $max = sizeof($nomes_frasesr_cee);
    //var_dump($max);
    $dados_frasesr_cee;

    for($j = 0; $j < $max;$j++)
    {
        var_dump($nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]);
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM frases_r where cod_frase_r='".$nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]."';");
        //var_dump($query1->result());
        foreach($query1->result() as $value){
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][0]=$value->id_frase_r;
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][1]=$value->cod_frase_r;
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][2]=$value->desc_frase_r;
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][3]=$value->desc_frase_r_ing;
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][4]=$value->desc_frase_r_esp;
                $dados_frasesr_cee[$j][5]=$value->diretiva_frase_r;
        }
    }
    var_dump($dados_frasesr_cee);
    return $dados_frasesr_cee;

} else {
        return;
    }

}
```

I guess the select considers this var `$nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]` empty and she is not. If I replace the var directly by some string I have on database it works perfectly, so I don't get what is the problem with the var.

Any hints? Thank you!

Result of the var_dump($query1);

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#21 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(29) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(43) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Is it an array? if so, you have to add comma's between them.

Comment: did u print the query ...like what kind of query is being fiered??\

Comment: @kees sonnema, sorry, but commas between what? thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I thought it could be an array. But it's not the problem. forgot what I've said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not escape the string ($nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]) and that probably leads to an invalid statement. 
In order to create a statement that is valid try this:

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM frases_r where cod_frase_r=?;", array($nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]));
```

Comment: i tried sjkm, dont work :( i'm really missing something here on this query in the part i add the array var.

Comment: print the sql statement in your script and post it here so we can see what is wrong with it

Comment: We want to know how the query looks like (string). Please post that.

Comment: Sorry, but im not getting what you pretend. You mean, like if it had any results?

Comment: print "SELECT * FROM frases_r where cod_frase_r='".$nomes_frasesr_cee[$j]."';"

Comment: SELECT * FROM frases_r where cod_frase_r=' R3';

Comment: coult it be that space between the first ' and the R3 that are causing me trouble?

Answer (score 1):

i have no idea why are you creating an extra array and looping through it again to get the same value.. and i see you are using the created array nowhere in the code(atleast in posted code)

try this

```
public function get_frasesr_by_cee($ficha_id){

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela_cee_r where id_ficha='".$ficha_id."'");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

foreach($query->result() as $row){
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM frases_r where cod_frase_r='".$row->cod_frase_r."'");
    //var_dump($query1->result());
    foreach($query1->result() as $value){
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->id_frase_r;
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->cod_frase_r;
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->desc_frase_r;
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->desc_frase_r_ing;
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->desc_frase_r_esp;
            $dados_frasesr_cee[]=$value->diretiva_frase_r;
    }        

var_dump($dados_frasesr_cee);
return $dados_frasesr_cee;

} else {
    return;
}

}
```

**NOTE: you really have to go through the CI's userguide and use active_record...JOINS mostly**
with join  you can do this with one query..

example

```
public function get_frasesr_by_cee($ficha_id){   
 $this->db->select('t.*,f.*');
 $this->db->from('tabela_cee_r'.' t');
 $this->db->join('frases_r'.' f','t.cod_frase_r=f.cod_frase_r','left');
 $this->db->where('t.id_ficha',$ficha_id) 
 return $this->db->get();
});
```

Comment: you are right, i dont need that extra cicle, i will remove it, thank you for that. But that doesn't solve my problem. Either the way you exposed to me does not work, i'm really missing something in that part of the select, he just doesnt get the value of my var, i dont know why since if i print it before the select the value is there. could i be missing a ", ' or some function so that he can understand the value of that var? Even the row->cod_frase_r gives no results :O